# How to keep user authenticated in my app (Firebase + React)?

Tags: reactjs, firebase, authentication, firebase-authentication, local-storage

In my app i have a page with sign in form. After successful login i can use all the features in the app but if i reload the page, the user is automatically kicked out of the app. How to prevent this from happening? (i sign in users with email and password)

I tried:

- setPersistence(auth, browserSessionPersistence)
- save user data to local storage (but i can't understand how to use them. Should i try to sign in user through email and password in useEffect or what idk)
- signInWithCustomToken (also tried to save a custom token which user receive after sign in and tried to sign in again with it)

Comment: On most browsers Firebase Authentication automatically persists and restores the user credentials, so you should have to set any persistence mode yourself as long as you follow the first snippet in the documentation on [getting the curent user](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/manage-users#get_the_currently_signed-in_user). If that isn't happening for you, edit your question to show the [minimal code that any of us can use to reproduce where you are stuck](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i've fixed this error, just use redux-persist to store data in localstorage. I know that isn't the best way but that's for my university